# Pull data into dataframe from oracle database in Pyspark 1.5

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, dataframe, jdbc, pyspark

I am facing pyspark issue. I want to retrieve data from an oracle database.
My main issue is to create the jdbc url.

I have tried two ways and both are falling in error.
Below is my code source. **Could you please help me building the right request**:
I precise that I am using Spark 1.5 (Spark 2.0 functions will not work).
Many thanks,

```
##### 
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
appName='Import-Data' 
try:
    sc.stop()
    except :
    print 'spark context does not exists'
else:
    print 'existing spark context stopped'
 conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName)
 conf.set("spark.executor.instances", "9")
 conf.set("spark.executor.cores", "4")
 conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "8g")
 sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
import re

sqlsc = SQLContext(sc)
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
sqlsc = SQLContext(sc)
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

#Connection a la base de donnees
#First way (YYYY is the user and XXXXXX is the password)
#MyDataFrame = sqlsc.read.load(source="jdbc",url="jdbc:oracle:thin://Server/DATABASE?   user=YYYY&password=XXXXXX",dbtable="schema.table")

#Second way
MyDataFrame = sqlsc.read.load(source="jdbc",url="jdbc:oracle:thin:YYYY/XXXXXX@Server:1521/DATABASE",dbtable="Schema.table")


#Here is the error I am facing:

Py4JJavaErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-82abab7efad2> in <module>()
----> 1 MyDataFrame.show(5)
/usr/iop/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate)
    254         +---+-----+
    255         """
--> 256         print(self._jdf.showString(n, truncate))
    257
    258     def __repr__(self):
/usr/iop/current/spark-client/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    536         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    537         return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
--> 538                 self.target_id, self.name)
    539
    540         for temp_arg in temp_args:
/usr/iop/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     34     def deco(*a, **kw):
     35         try:
---> 36             return f(*a, **kw)
     37         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
 38             s = e.java_exception.toString()
/usr/iop/current/spark-client/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o152.showString.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SparkContext has been shutdown
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1814)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1835)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1848)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1385)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1385)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:1903)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.collect(DataFrame.scala:1384)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1314)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:178)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

 Here are the environments variable set:
export PATH=/gpfs/user/$USER/env_python2/bin:/gpfs/user/$USER/env_python3/bin:$PATH
#ajout de R
export PATH=/gpfs/user/common/R-devel/R-3.4.1/bin:$PATH
#Lib pour Jupyter
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/gpfs/user/common/jupyter/sqlite/sqlite/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/gpfs/user/common/jupyter/sqlite/sqlite/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export SPARK_CLASSPATH=/soft/ora1120/db/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar:/gpfs/user/e547041/jupyter/toolbox/spark-csv_2.10-0.1.jar
```

Note: I am using Jupiter under spak 1.5

Comment: Please post the full traceback. Also out of look of it, it is possible that your code fails somewhere else and the failure is not related to the code you've posted. This code should do almost nothing - therefore shouldn't kill the context.

Comment: Hi user6910411!, In fact I am pretty sure that the problem  is coming from my url string cause I have performed a step by step. And it fails at the dataframe loading request. But I will poste the whole code and environments variable in 1 min

Comment: Now the whole code is posted. My idea is that the string to connect to the database is not the good one. I really need to find the right way to connect a oracle database with jdbc connection. From my perspective, this is the bottleneck on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code clearly indicates that the JVM `SparkContext` is not running

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o152.showString.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SparkContext has been shutdown
```

This can happen if the Python `SparkContext` has been improperly stopped, or when there is some configuration issue preventing Java `SparkContext` from starting.

In this state, any kind of action, not necessarily `jdbc` will fail.

To resolve this problem you should determine why the context doesn't properly start. Looking at the code you posted (it is hard to fully analyze it without the context and proper indentation) it it is likely that

```
try:
   sc.stop()
```

leaves your driver in some undefined state.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. Even if there is a sc.stop() in the try, there is an initialization of the spark context, after that.  sc = SparkContext(conf=conf). with this code, Jvm is running. and for information, several actions performed did worked